# Roothaan equations and Galerkin method

Tags: quantum-mechanics, galerkin

When we do Hartree-Fock computations by solving the Roothaan equations $FC = SC \varepsilon$ is it a Galerkin method?

Comment: Also, I think this question is a good fit here, but if you have any questions about electronic structure theory that don't pick up steam here, I would say you should try to ask them on [Matter Modeling SE](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that equation comes about from making the approximation that we can write the wavefunction in terms of a finite basis.

You won't typically see the phrase Galerkin used in the chemical literature, but the linear combination of atomic orbitals (LCAO) approach is a Galerkin method. Here is at least [one paper](http://www.numdam.org/item/M2AN_2000__34_4_749_0.pdf), written by a mathematician about electronic structure methods, describing it as a Galerkin method.